# Ayuda con Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo StoredProcedure C#

Tags: c#, stored-procedure

Me encuentro programando una aplicación en C# para extraer los procedimientos almacenados de una base de datos y generar los script correspondientes, el problema que se me da, es que al obtener los objetos de tipo StoreProcedure, este me trae los SystemStoreProcedures también, he buscando información pero no he encontrado código que los filtre, se me ocurrió hacer lo siguiente:

1) Obtengo los procedimientos de una base de datos:

```
StoredProcedureCollection spcoll = srv.Databases["demo"].StoredProcedures;
```

2) Luego recorro la lista con un foreach para filtar los store procedures que sean de sistema y los dejo en una nueva lista de donde finalmente obtendré los procedimientos almacenados que deseo sacar.

```
List<StoredProcedure> lista = new List<StoredProcedure>();

foreach (StoredProcedure item in spcoll)
{
   if (item.IsSystemObject == false)
      {
         lista.Add(item);
       }
}
```

Esto funciona de forma correcta, me agrega los StoreProcedure que corresponde a la base de datos y que no son de sistema a la lista, el problema que en realizar esto se demora demasiado entre 10-20 segundos, mi consulta es si hay una forma más eficiente de realizar esto.

Saludos.

Comment: ¿En qué parte es donde está tardando, al momento de obtenerlos o al momento de recorrer la lista? Esto para ir descartando y saber en donde se encuentra la falla. Otra cosa, ¿cuál es la cantidad de datos que estás utilizando? Si hablamos de miles o de cientros de miles, talvés el tiempo que está tardando es el necesario.

Comment: yo probaria a cronometrar cuanto tarda y contaria el numero total de elementos por los que pasa, quizas tarde lo que toca. Sin embargo, si lo que necesitas es poder trabajar y hacer otra cosa mientras se carga, te recomiendo que hagas la carga de los stored procedure en un backgroundworker de tal forma que la aplicacion no parecera que este muerta, incluso podrias poner una progress bar para que el usuario sepa que se estan haciendo cosas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que podrías realizar es crear un hilo secundario para que la aplicación no se cuelgue. Esto lo podrías realizar crear un método con ese código que escribiste y llamarlo desde un hilo secundario (Theard).

Acá te dejo unos links para que véas como se hacen:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_multithreading.htm

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/363377/how-do-i-run-a-simple-bit-of-code-in-a-new-thread

Hay información sobre los Thread y los BackgroundWorker.

Saludos

Comment: me sirvió mucho lo que me recomendaste, agregué el Theard y ya no se cuelga el proceso al extraer 420 jobs desde un servidor gracias :)

Comment: Muchas gracias a vos.