# System.InvalidOperationException trabajando con hilos

Tags: c#, hilos

El código es el siguiente, mas abajo la explicación..

```
    Thread hilo = new Thread(NuevoHilo);
    hilo.Start(item);

    private void NuevoHilo(object item)
             {
              rtxMensajes = new Mensajes().NuevoMensaje(rtxMensajes, item.ToString(), tbxArchivo.Text, Color.Green);           
             }

    public RichTextBox NuevoMensaje(RichTextBox rtb, string unidad, string archivo, Color color)
             {
                string avance = "\r\n";
                rtb.SelectionStart = rtb.TextLength;  <---- EXCEPCION!!!
                rtb.SelectionLength = 0;

                rtb.SelectionColor = color;
                rtb.AppendText(String.Format("Se copio el archivo {0} en la unidad {1} {2}", archivo, unidad, avance));
                rtb.SelectionColor = rtb.ForeColor;
                return rtb;
             }
```

Cuando se ejecuta el método `NuevoHilo` y este instancia un objeto de la clase `Mensaje` que a su vez llama a un método de esta clase y que toma como parámetro un objeto `RichTextBox`, se produce una excepción del tipo `System.InvalidOperationException`, que me da la siguiente descripción;

> Operación no válida a través de subprocesos: Se tuvo acceso al control 'rtxMensajes' desde un subproceso distinto a aquel en que lo creó.

Decir que el objeto que paso como parametro es un RichTextBox que tengo creado en el Form1, intento que cada vez que lanzo el hilo me escriba el resultado el el RichTextBox llamado `rtxMensajes`

Comment: El error es claro. Solo se puede acceder a los controles desde el hilo principal. Mira [este enlace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms171728(v=vs.110).aspx) donde tienes una amplia explicación. De todas maneras te recomiendo no trabajar con threads directamente,usa mejor `BackgroundWorker` o `Task`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cuando vayas a acceder a los controles creados en el hilo principal debes hacerlo de 2 maneras: 1 Llamando al método Invoke de tu formulario o usando BackgroundWorkers.

```
//Usando Invoke
Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() =>
{
  //Aqui va el código que modifica controles creados en el hilo principal
}));

//Usando BackgroundWorker
private void ThreadSafe(Action callback,Form form)
{
    BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
    worker.RunWorkerCompleted += (obj, e) =>
    {
        if (form.InvokeRequired)
            form.Invoke(callback);
        else
            callback();
    };
    worker.RunWorkerAsync();
}

//Lo llamas de esta manera
ThreadSafe(() =>{
   //Código que modifica controles creados en el hilo principal
}, this)  //this si estas en la clase del formulario principal
```

En fin tu código quedaría de estas dos maneras (usa la que desees)

```
 public RichTextBox NuevoMensaje(RichTextBox rtb, string unidad, string archivo, Color color)
 {
    ThreadSafe(()=>{
        string avance = "\r\n";
        rtb.SelectionStart = rtb.TextLength;  <---- EXCEPCION!!!
        rtb.SelectionLength = 0;

        rtb.SelectionColor = color;
        rtb.AppendText(String.Format("Se copio el archivo {0} en la unidad {1} {2}", archivo, unidad, avance));
        rtb.SelectionColor = rtb.ForeColor;
    }, this);

    return rtb;
 }
```

o de esta:

```
public RichTextBox NuevoMensaje(RichTextBox rtb, string unidad, string archivo, Color color)
 {
    Invoke(new MethodInvoker(()=>{
       string avance = "\r\n";
        rtb.SelectionStart = rtb.TextLength;  <---- EXCEPCION!!!
        rtb.SelectionLength = 0;

        rtb.SelectionColor = color;
        rtb.AppendText(String.Format("Se copio el archivo {0} en la unidad {1} {2}", archivo, unidad, avance));
        rtb.SelectionColor = rtb.ForeColor;
    });
    return rtb;
 }
```

Prueba y me dices. Saludos

Comment: ¿También tu crees que es mas conveniente utilizar los BackgroundWorkers que los hilos? ¿Alguna razón? Gracias

Comment: Revisa esto: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/es-ES/5a8f96e5-b836-45c4-9c5c-03966a159634/backgroundworker-thread-cual-es-mas-eficiente?forum=vcses  y  este link también, coincido más con este último http://www.forosdelweb.com/f29/backgroundworker-0-threading-795883/

Comment: Acá te dejo un link sobre hilos. https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/80876/ayuda-con-microsoft-sqlserver-management-smo-storedprocedure-c/81014#81014

Comment: No termino de entender porque pones como parametro el "this" que hace referencia al form...  En mi caso, el metodo NuevoMensaje esta en la clase Mnesajes, no en el FORM1, por lo tanto, ¿Que debo poner en vez del this?

Comment: Me ha funcionando cambiando el "this" por el "Kopipaste.ActiveForm", no se muy bien si es correcto lo que estoy haciendo...

Comment: El segundo parámetro que es el que no entienes, es el formulario donde creas el RichTextBox, en mi caso era donde mismo estaba creada la función donde iba a llamar a **ThreadSafe**, en tu caso si accediendo a Kopipaste.ActiveForm accedes al formulario donde lo creas entonces ya lo solucionastes ;)