# Como usar BackGroundWorker en C#

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

tengo una consulta.
Quisiera usar el backgroundworker en mi aplicación, pero no tengo ni idea como realizarlo. Mi aplicación toma bastante tiempo en realizar ciertas validaciones, mientras esto se realiza, esta queda congelada. La idea que tengo es colocar un botón **CANCELAR VALIDACIÓN**. ¿Como pudiera realizarlo?.
Este es mi código, aquí se realiza todo el proceso.

```
  void Listar()
    {
        try
        {
            CN_Guias guias = new CN_Guias();
            DateTime Hoy = DateTime.Today;
            string fecha_actual = Hoy.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
            string mes, año;
            mes = txt_mes.Text;
            año = txt_anno.Text;
            if (txt_ruta.Text == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Ingresar Ruta por favor.!!!", "Ingresar Datos", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
            }
            else if (txt_mes.Text == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Ingrese el Mes por favor.!!!", "Ingresar Datos", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
            }
            else if (txt_anno.Text == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Ingrese el Año por favor.!!!", "Ingresar Datos", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
            }
            else
            {
           DataTable dtImagenes = 
           guias.Listar_Guias_xMes_xAño(Convert.ToInt32(mes), 
           Convert.ToInt32(año));
                int cantidad_imagen_db = dtImagenes.Rows.Count;
                pgb_cargando.Visible = true;
                pgb_cargando.Maximum = cantidad_imagen_db;
                pgb_cargando.Step = 1;
                pgb_cargando.Value = 0;

                //INICIO FOR
                btn_listar.Enabled = false;
                txt_mes.Enabled = false;
                txt_anno.Enabled = false;
                foreach (DataRow row in dtImagenes.Rows)
                {
                    string nom_imagen_db = row["NroGuia"].ToString().TrimEnd(' ');
                    string[] archivos = Directory.GetFiles(txt_ruta.Text, nom_imagen_db + ".*");
                    string[] archivos2 = Directory.GetFiles(txt_ruta.Text, nom_imagen_db + "_*");
                    if (pgb_cargando.Value <= cantidad_imagen_db)
                    {
                        pgb_cargando.PerformStep();
                    }
                     if (archivos.Length == 0 && archivos2.Length==0) {
                         string f_guia = row["FechaGuia"].ToString();
                         guias.InsertarGuiasValidadas(nom_imagen_db,
                                                         Convert.ToDateTime(f_guia),
                                                         DateTime.Now, "NO"); 
                    }
                    }
                MessageBox.Show("Se realizo la validación correctamente");
                btn_listar.Enabled = true;
                txt_mes.Enabled = true;
                txt_anno.Enabled = true;
                Limpiar();
                //FIN FOR
                //btn_validar.Enabled = true;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Espero, puedan ayudarme. Gracias.

[image: Formulario de Validación de Imágenes]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La clase `BackgroundWorker` le permite ejecutar una operación en un `subproceso` dedicado independiente. Las operaciones que requieren mucho tiempo como descargas y las transacciones de base de datos pueden provocar la interfaz de usuario **(UI)** para parecer como si ha dejado de responder mientras se están ejecutando. Si desea una `IU` dinámica y está sufriendo grandes retrasos asociados con estas operaciones, la clase `BackgroundWorker` proporciona una solución adecuada.

Para ejecutar una operación lenta en segundo plano, se crea un `BackgroundWorker` y escuchar los eventos que notifican el progreso de la operación y una señal cuando finaliza la operación. Puede crear el `BackgroundWorker` mediante programación o arrástrelo al formulario desde el componentes pestaña de la cuadro de herramientas. Si crea el `BackgroundWorker` en el Diseñador de `Windows Forms`, aparecerá en la Bandeja de componentes y sus propiedades se mostrará en la ventana Propiedades.

Para configurar una operación en segundo plano, agregue un controlador de eventos para el evento `DoWork`. Llame a la operación que requieren mucho tiempo en este controlador de eventos. Para iniciar la operación, llame a `RunWorkerAsync`. Para recibir notificaciones de actualizaciones de progreso, controle el evento `ProgressChanged`. Para recibir una notificación cuando se complete la operación, controle el evento `RunWorkerCompleted`.

Debes colocar lo que vayas a realizar dentro de la función `DoWork` e iniciar el `BackgroundWorker` para que trabaje de manera asíncrona `backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();`:

```
private DataTable dtImagenes = new DataTable();
private string ruta;

void Listar()
{
    try
    {
        CN_Guias guias = new CN_Guias();
        DateTime Hoy = DateTime.Today;
        string fecha_actual = Hoy.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
        string mes, año;
        mes = txt_mes.Text;
        año = txt_anno.Text;
        ruta = txt_ruta.Text;
        if (txt_ruta.Text == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Ingresar Ruta por favor.!!!", "Ingresar Datos", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
        }
        else if (txt_mes.Text == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Ingrese el Mes por favor.!!!", "Ingresar Datos", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
        }
        else if (txt_anno.Text == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Ingrese el Año por favor.!!!", "Ingresar Datos", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
        }
        else
        {
            dtImagenes =
            guias.Listar_Guias_xMes_xAño(Convert.ToInt32(mes),
            Convert.ToInt32(año));
            pgb_cargando.Visible = true;
            pgb_cargando.Maximum = dtImagenes.Rows.Count;
            pgb_cargando.Step = 1;
            pgb_cargando.Value = 0;
            btn_listar.Enabled = false;
            txt_mes.Enabled = false;
            txt_anno.Enabled = false;
            if(!backgroundWorker1.IsBusy)
                backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
    }
}

private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        //INICIO FOR
        int i = 0;
        foreach (DataRow row in dtImagenes.Rows)
        {
            if (!backgroundWorker1.CancellationPending)
            {
                string nom_imagen_db = row["NroGuia"].ToString().TrimEnd(' ');
                string[] archivos = Directory.GetFiles(ruta, nom_imagen_db + ".*");
                string[] archivos2 = Directory.GetFiles(ruta, nom_imagen_db + "_*");
                if (archivos.Length == 0 && archivos2.Length == 0)
                {
                    string f_guia = row["FechaGuia"].ToString();
                    guias.InsertarGuiasValidadas(nom_imagen_db,
                                                Convert.ToDateTime(f_guia),
                                                DateTime.Now, "NO");
                }
                backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(i++);
            }
            else
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
                return;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
    }
}

private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    //REPORTAR PROGRESO
    pgb_cargando.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
}

private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Cancelled)
        MessageBox.Show("Se ha cancelado el proceso.");
    else if (e.Error != null)
        MessageBox.Show("Error");
    else
        MessageBox.Show("Se realizo la validación correctamente");
    Habilitar();
    Limpiar();
    //FIN FOR
}

private void Habilitar()
{
    btn_listar.Enabled = true;
    txt_mes.Enabled = true;
    txt_anno.Enabled = true;
}
```

Te dejo la fuente si quieres más [información](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker?view=netframework-4.7.2).

Comment: Hola **@Victor Perdomo**, realice lo que comentas, pero me manda un mensaje indicando: Operación no valida a través de subprocesos. Se tuvo acceso al control "nombre_de_mi_boton" desde un subproceso distinto a aquel en que lo creó. ¿Que debería modificar para que funcione?.

Comment: Lo que pasa es que estas utilizando controles creados desde el hilo principal dentro del `BackgroundWorker` esto te genera ese problema. La solución es guardar esa información en variables fuera de la función o utilizando `Invoke`. [Solución con Invoke](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/106391/system-invalidoperationexception-trabajando-con-hilos?rq=1)

Comment: Ya modifique la respuesta prueba a ver si te funciona de esa manera.

Comment: **@Victor Perdomo**, muchas gracias. Efectivamente, el problema era por llamar a ciertos procesos desde otro subproceso. Modifique lo necesario y también funciona. Mi pregunta es, ¿Si quisiera activar la cancelación, que debería poner?--> Use esto:  bgw_1.CancelAsync(); en mi botón cancelar pero no funciona.(también active workersupportscancellation).

Comment: Debes habilitar la cancelación en la propiedad `WorkerSupportsCancellation` colocalo en `true` y en la función `DoWork` debes agregar `e.Cancel = backgroundWorker1.CancellationPending;`

Comment: Coloca `e.Cancel = bgw_1.CancellationPending;` dentro del ciclo `foreach` para que verifique en cada vuelta si se esta pidiendo cancelar.

Comment: Acabo de editar mi respuesta revisala.

Comment: **@Victor Perdomo**, realice las modificaciones que me indicas, pero ahora la aplicación no realiza la validación. De frente me manda el mensaje que realizo la validación correctamente. Normalmente demora entre 10 a 15 minutos, pero ahora en 2 segundos manda el mensaje y revise mi base datos, no figura ningún registro. Voy a regresar a mi código anterior e ir verificando otra vez. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Coloca un `breakpoint` y ve si se esta cumpliendo con la condición y el ciclo.

Comment: Te mostraba el mensaje porque al cancelar el evento te manda directamente a la función `RunWorkerCompleted` por lo que debes validar si se esta cancelando para mostrar el mensaje o no. Ya modifique mi respuesta verifica a ver.

Comment: Revise el Debug, en esta linea : else
            MessageBox.Show("Se realizo la validación correctamente"); --> Entra directamente aca. Nunca realiza lo que esta en el dowork!!

Comment: Entra a la función `DoWork`?

Comment: no entra al DoWork!! Se salta.

Comment: Lo que esta pasando es que la función `DoWork` no esta referenciada con el `BackGroundWorker` si es lo que me indicas. Debes añadirla. `bgw_1.DoWork += backgroundWorker1_DoWork;`

Comment: Mi backgroundworker se llama: bgw_1 . Por que debería referenciarlo?

Comment: **@Victor Perdomo**,en que momento debería llamar al **void Listar()** , estoy verificando y en ningún momento lo usa??

Comment: El listar lo colocas en cualquier lugar fuera del `BackGroundWoker` es el que te va a iniciar el trabajo. `Listar()` tiene la función `RunWorkAsync` así que es la que inicia todo.

Comment: Muchas Gracias **@Victor Perdomo** por su tiempo. Logre realizar lo que necesitaba.

Comment: Que bueno amigo tranquilo éxitos con tus proyectos.