# backgroundWorker y RichTextBox C#

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

Estoy haciendo un form y uso backgroundWorker ya que tarda unas dos horas en hacer todas las operaciones. Tengo un richTextBox, para informar al usuario que empezo ha trabajar, y quiero ir poniendo diferentes frases.

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (backgroundWorker1.IsBusy != true)
        {
            //inicia el proceso
            backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(box.Text = "HOLA");
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(box.Text = "ADIOS");
        }
    }
```

He puesto esto, haciendo pruebas para ir comprendiendo como funciona, y mi problema es despues de Thread.Sleep, me dice que backgroundWorker1 ya esta trabajando. Quiero escribir el valor de varias variables en el box. Antes de hacerlo con backgroundWorker lo hacia asi:

```
BoxText.Text += "Selecciona la carpeta donde tengas la version de R. " + "\n" + rutaR;
BoxText.Text += "InputPath--> La carpeta donde estan los ficheros a subir" + ruta;
BoxText.Text += "Valor MDA. Si no haces check, es NO." + auxCarpetaNombre;
```

Como puedo hacer para poner todos los BoxText.Text que quiera. Todos se van a poner a la vez. Habia pensado en guardar el valor de la frase en un String, pero despues de la frase, necesito mostrar el valor de variables, no me vale.

Comment: Indagando mas por el foro, encontre una solucion que me ha funcionado, por si le vale a alguien mas, no la he encontrado buscando lo que queria, por eso la dejo.
https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/106391/system-invalidoperationexception-trabajando-con-hilos?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que estás accediendo al interfaz desde el thread del backgroundworker me imagino. Eso no se puede hacer y te dará un error si lo intentas.

Para acceder al thread del interfaz (o thread principal) tienes que usar la solución del enlace que has puesto, o usar los eventos que el propio backgroundworker tiene para eso.

En este caso lo más fácil es poner la propiedad WorkerReportsProgress = True y luego dentro de tu evento DoWork, haces una llamada al ReportProgress.

```
backgroundWorker2.ReportProgress(1, "Linea de texto");
```

Y en el evento de ProgressChanged ya puedes interactuar con la interfaz. De hecho, para eso precisamente es ese evento:

```
    private void backgroundWorker2_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
      progresoDescarga.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
      richTextBox1.Text += (e.UserState + "");
    }
```

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda, al final, despues de muchas pruebas y errores, lo solucione con un delegado y un evento. Gracias.